# access user's microsoft account email id from my app in windows phone 8

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

I'm looking to access an email id of user that is used for marketplace in wp8.  Email address chooser task is only to obtain the email address of a contact, not from user's mail id set in mail account of phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to privacy concerns it is not possible to retrieve the account ID. If you just want to identify the user you can use `UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID2")` (more information on the WP8 version [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/11/migrating-anids-to-windows-phone-8.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Also **ANID2 is bounded to** the the **Windows Live Account Id**, and the **Publisher GUID**. So, applications from **different publisher will get different values of ANID2**.

This link dives into a bit more details-   [ANID2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/7e265aed-1719-4158-bc98-5d985e694c4c/userextendedproperties-anid-anid2-changes-in-wp8?forum=wpdevelop)

extract :

**The following holds true for Windows Phone 8 too.**

The format in WP7 was like (I x-ed out a few chars): **`A=E32ACBXXXXXXXXX3B337B68CFFFFFFFF&E=d59&W=1`**

In WP7 it was necessary to parse the value after A= up to &E= as the other values could change over time.